# How to return object from API call using RxJS, Axios and TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, rxjs

I'm making an API call to get the employee's details and using RxJS and TypeScript. I wanted to store them in a Map as key and value pairs like below:

```
function getEmps() {
  const empMap = new Map();

  rx
  .from(axios.get(api_url))
  .pipe(
   catchError((err) => {
          logger.error('Error in making api call', {
            error: err
          });

          throw new Error('Error in making api call');
        })
      )
   )
  .pipe(
    map((emps)=>{
      .....
      emps.forEach((empObj) =>{
         empMap.set(id, empObj);
      })
    })
  );
  return empMap;
}
console.log(getMap);
```

But finally, it's returning an empty map. What is the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To transform a `Promise<T>` into an `Observable<T>` you need to use the `defer` and `from` utility functions from RxJS

```js
import { defer, from } from 'rxjs';

function getSomething() {
  return defer(() => from(axios.get(...)))
}
```

Here's an example with using JavaScript's API's

```js
import { defer, from } from 'rxjs';

async function getSomething(): Promise<Map> {
  const emps = await axios.get(...)
  const empMap = new Map();
  emps.forEach((empObj) => empMap.set(empObj.id, empObj))
  return empMap;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to return Observable<T>, I want to return a Map from that function.

Comment: That's just not how asynchronous or reactive programming works… You get an observable which you could think as if it was a channel where you're going to get notifications of "maps". Perhaps you'd be more comfortable by using `async/await` API's with promises. Let me update the answer

Comment: Hi, I tried it, it's giving the error like this ```Type 'Promise<Map<any, any>>' is missing the following properties from type 'Map<any, any>': clear, delete, forEach, get, and 7 more.```. And Thank you for your response.

Comment: You must have an error somewhere else. I've put together [this small working example](https://codepen.io/NanoSpicer/pen/BammEaV) for reference

Comment: I solved it. I just need Map<any, any> instead of Promise<Map<any, any>>. I extracted values from it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Very good then :)